# Thumb images are not displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using carrierwave and minimagic gems. This is the code in my index view to display the thumb images:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  Quantity  :<%= item.qty %><br>
  Price  : <%= number_to_currency(item.price, unit: "RS " ) %><br>
  <%= image_tag item.image_url(:thumb)%>
</div>
```

This is the code available in the `Image_uploader`:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
```

It works without `:thumb`; the image is displayed as is.

```
<%= image_tag @item.image_url %>
```

But it cannot be viewed in thumb format. It displays the image name and a broken image icon on the localhost preview.

Please help me solve this.

Comment: are the image thumbnails actually created?

Comment: try this <%= image_tag @item.image.url(:thumb) %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following code block it's working properly.

```
  <%= image_tag item.image_url(:thumb)%>
```

Comment: It's same as my ans ...in rails brackets are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<%= image_tag item.thumbnail_url(:thumb) %>
```

OR

```
<%= image_tag item.avatar.thumb.url %>
```

Go Thought this link, it will help you. [reference](https://www.sitepoint.com/processing-images-with-carrierwave/)

Comment: Try this one `<%= image_tag @item.image(:thumb).url %>`

Comment: OR this one `<%= image_tag(@item.image_url(:thumb).to_s) %>`

Comment: try this <%= image_tag @item.image.url(:thumb) %>

Comment: The issue was with the image that i have uploaded.Now it's working.BTW thanks for your kind support